# Add conditions to existed WP_Query in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some filter to select needed posts like:

```
function exclude_post($query) {
    if ($query->is_home) {

       // Do some PHP code

    }    
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post');
```

How can I add new conditions to existed **WP_Query** instance `$query`?

Comment: $query = new WP_Query( $args); $args is condition array i guess

Answer (score 8):

If you want to modify your query with a filter, you can use `$query->set('post_type', 'post');` in your function, just addapt with your parameter.

If you want to modify the main loop, you can use this :

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bob'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

a snippet from codex see more here [wp query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: But when I create new WP_Query instance I'll lost initial `$query` and create new. But I want to add some conditions to existed one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a custom list of posts but you don't want to lose the current `wp_query`? Easy, use `wp_reset_query()`!

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( $argument_array );
//... Do all you have to do with the query ... 
wp_reset_query(); // This will restore the original query.
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to wp_reset_query() and to provide more control over your query, here is what works for me:

You can add to the the $args array with array_push(). Then, you just create a new WP_Query. Of course, this will only work if you still have the $args variable set.

In your code, you can write:

```
$new_arg = array('tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => get_query_var('taxonomy'),
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => get_query_var('term'),
                ),
            )
);
array_push($args,$new_arg);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In my code above, I am simply using array_push to add a new array element to the same array that WP_QUERY is using. Then, I am simply passing it back into WP_QUERY.

I hope this helps someone.